# Impact of increasing the MAXMSGL parm of a receiver channel

Tags: channel, mq

What is the impact of increasing the MAXMSGL parm of a receiver channel?"  Does it automatically increase the amount of memory allocated for the channel, regardless of the size of the messages that flow across the channel?  For a cluster-receiver channel, which typically supports multiple channel instances, does it increase the memory allocation for each channel instances?  (example: if the channel is supporting 10 connections, and we increase MAXMSGL from 4MB to 100MB, does it increase memory usage from 40MB to 1GB?

We are using MQ v7.5.0.3 on AIX.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  If the message size is 100KB that flows across the channel then you will see no difference.  On the other hand, if the message size jumps to 100MB then the memory size will increase but I don't believe it will hit 1GB.